# Firefox crashes very often - Attempting to load the system libmoon

Tags: firefox

Today Firefox started crashing whenever I'm trying to open the preferences editor, and also often during normal navigation. If I start Firefox from a terminal, when it crashes it returns the message: Attempting to load the system libmoon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you've run into an instance of this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/moon/+bug/538796

The workaround for now seems to be removing the moonlight browser
plugin:

```
apt-get purge moonlight-plugin-core moonlight-plugin-mozilla
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue caused by Moonlight plugin. Uninstall *moonlight-plugin-mozilla* to solve your problem.

```
sudo apt-get purge moonlight-plugin-mozilla
```

If you still need Moonlight, then you could try the 3.0 preview version from:

http://www.go-mono.org/moonlight/prerelease.aspx